# why i can't use isLongPress() to detect back button long press

Tags: android

`event.isLongPress()` always wrong,code below

```
alertdialogue.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override

            public boolean onKey( DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )

            {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 

                && event.isLongPress())

                {
```

Can anybody give me some help?…

Answer (score 0):

To detect a long press of the back button, use **onKeyDown** to mark the start of the press and record the time. Then, in **onKeyUp**, calculate the duration and check if it qualifies as a long press based on your desired duration.

```
private long backPressTime = 0;
private static final long LONG_PRESS_DURATION = 1000; // Set your desired long press duration in milliseconds

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        backPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        long pressDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - backPressTime;
        if (pressDuration >= LONG_PRESS_DURATION) {
            // Long press of the back button detected
            // Handle your long press logic here
            return true;
        } else {
            // Short press of the back button detected
            // Handle your short press logic here if needed
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: i just tried ,but still can't work,when i use setonkey in 
alertdialog it seems worked .But it always conflict with third part softinput,goes false.The effection of onkeydown,up worse than setonkey. Conflict with alertdialog and softinput both !